# Where are Dart ord() and chr() functions?

Tags: dart

I can't find a way to `ord()` or `chr()` in Dart:

```
print(ord("f")); // should be 102
print(chr(0x41)); // should be A
```

Where are these methods?

I'm talking about functions like in PHP.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you need to `ord()`, you simply use this getter:

```dart
print("ABC".codeUnits); // [65, 66, 67]
```

And if you need to construct a string from these:

```dart
print(new String.fromCharCodes([65, 66, 67])); // ABC
```

So in your case:

```dart
print("f".codeUnits.first); // 102
print(new String.fromCharCode(0x41); // "A"
```

Note: there is `fromCharCode()` and `fromCharCodes()`.